# Trouble with getting data from newly created input fields via Add button into database

Tags: javascript, php, html

So the problem is that the database is accepting only the data entered into the first input field.
 PHP

```
   <form class = "spendings" method ="POST" action="InsertToDatabase.php">
 <div id="numbering">ITEM 1: </div>
 <div class="entry">
 <label for= "item" class= "items">Item Name: </label>
 <input type="text" name="enterItems" id="enterItems" placeholder = "Please Enter The Item Name"></input>
  <label for ="price" class="price"> Price: </label>
  <input type = "number" name="enterPrice" id="enterPrice"  placeholder="Please Enter The Price" />
 </div>
<div id="add">
</div>
   <input type ="button" id = "more_items" onclick ="addMore()" value = "Add More">
   <button type = "submit" class="submit">Submit</button>

 </form>
```

insertToDatabase.php

```
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $user= "root";
$password= '';
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, '') or die("Could not connect");
$select = mysql_select_db("sharjeel",$conn);
$enterNames = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['enterItems']);
$enterNumbers = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['enterPrice']);
if($enterNames != '')
$msql="INSERT INTO `spendings` (itemName, Price) VALUES ('$enterNames', '$enterNumbers')";
$result= mysql_query( $msql, $conn);
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

and the JS

```
var item =1;
function addMore(){
item++;

var addDiv= document.getElementById("add");
var divTest = document.createElement("form");

divTest.innerHTML=' <form class = "spendings" method ="POST" action="insertToDatabase.php"><div id="numbering">ITEM '+ item + ':</div><div class="entry"><label for= "item" class= "items">Item Name: </label> <input type="text" class="enterItems" placeholder = "Please Enter The Item Name" /><label for ="price" class="price"> Price: </label><input type = "number" class="enterPrice" placeholder= "Please Enter The Price" /></div></form>';

addDiv.appendChild(divTest);

 }//end addMore
```

The first input field add the data into the database; however, after clicking "Add more" button and entering data into the newly created field the data is not entered intor the database. 
Thank you for you reply

Comment: maybe you only need the name attribute in the input fileds !

Comment: your fields name must be array enterItems[] and enterPrice[] in the first field and in your JavaScript field of add more

Comment: can you please elaborate? because now it is giving me the undefined index error.

Answer (score 0):

change name attribute to array from string i.er `name="enterItems[]"` and `name="enterPrice[]"` and use loop on the php to insert data into the database.

You also dont need to clone whole form again. Just clone content inside the form.

Comment: which loop are you talking about?

Comment: Ive elaborated the suggestion using your code in another answer to this question hope you find this usefull now

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is in the If statement , you forgot to use '{}'
and regardless of the inserting only one value into your database, just add into your database table spendings id that holds unique identifier or primary key.
it should look like this.

[image]

this should be your insertToDatabase.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Your database");
$enterNames =$_POST['enterItems'];
$enterNumbers = $_POST['enterPrice'];
if($enterNames != ''){
$msql= "INSERT INTO `spendings` (itemName, Price) VALUES ('$enterNames', '$enterNumbers')";
$result= mysqli_query( $conn,$msql);
header('Location: index.php');
}
mysqli_close($conn);    

?>
```

Comment: It already has ID and it is the same. I changed the if and still it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some of the changes to your code just to make you understand how can you achieve what you want.

HTML

```
<div class="entry">
<label for= "item" class= "items">Item Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="enterItems[]" id="enterItems" placeholder = "Please Enter The Item Name"></input>
<label for ="price" class="price"> Price: </label>
<input type = "number" name="enterPrice[]" id="enterPrice"  placeholder="Please Enter The Price" />
</div>
<div id="add">
</div>
<input type ="button" id = "more_items" onclick ="addMore()" value = "Add More">
<button type = "submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var item =1;
function addMore(){
item++;
var addDiv= document.getElementById("add");
var divTest= document.getElementsByClassName('entry')[0],
clone = divTest.cloneNode(true); // true means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
clone.id = item;
addDiv.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enterItems'])){
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($_POST['enterItems']); $i++) { // this is the loop i was talking about
    // you will need to create and execute your mysql command here in order to insert all the  records into the database.
    echo $_POST['enterItems'][$i]; 
    echo $_POST['enterPrice'][$i];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply. However, this is still giving me the same problem. I cant seem to insert the second input fields data into the database and it is aso cloning the "add" and "submit" button as well.

Comment: Replace your html with mine as well and give it a try

Comment: Ive tested before posting here it wasnt cloning the submit button

Comment: Its working perfectly. Although, I am ashamed that I had to ask you guys for help, but I am thankful for the help.